# How can I place a text below another text when they're in the same row but in different columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering how can I place a text below another text when they're in the same row but in different columns?

This is image shows my current situation and goals. I applied a border attribute to see how the row and columns were distributed.

[image]

This is my HTML code:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row mt-3">

  <div class="col-7 border d-flex justify-content-start">
    <p class="mb-3 b d-block text-right" style="color: #00A0DE; font-size: 50px;">Choose it</p>
    <br> <br>
    <p class="d-block b border" style="padding-top:40px; color: #323e48;">Select your favorite <br>product</p>
    <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Number1.PNG" alt="" style="align-self: center;" width="100" height="100" style="margin-left:500px;">

  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="semirounded-square-2">
      <div>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Character_1.png" alt="" width="250" style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how can I distribute my HTML elements in a way that it resembles the desired result?

Comment: Try this <div class="col-5" style:"float:left">

Comment: are you flexible enough to change your HTML structure ?

Comment: @Viira Sure, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Perhaps think of there being 3 columns, the first with the two bits of text, the second with the number image and the third with the person and blue background. Then you can remove much of the fixed margin etc settings and let bootstrap sort out the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this behavior for mobile screens you can change the display property for col-7's flex property on responsive view

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-7.d-flex {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row mt-3">
    
        <div class="col-7 border d-flex justify-content-start">
            <p class="mb-3 b d-block text-right" style="color: #00A0DE; font-size: 50px;">Choose it</p>
            <br> <br>
            <p class="d-block b border" style="padding-top:40px; color: #323e48;">Select your favorite <br>product</p>
            
    
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 d-flex">
          <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Number1.PNG" alt="" 
            style="align-self: center;" width="100" height="100" style="margin-left:500px;">
            <div class="semirounded-square-2">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" 
                    alt="" width="250"  style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Make sure to wrap both images in a same div

Else

If you want the same behavior desktop view you can try this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<div class="row mt-3">
    
        <div class="col-5 border d-flex justify-content-start">
            <p class=" text-right" style="color: #00A0DE; font-size: 50px;">Choose it <span class='d-block' style="color:black; font-size:20px;">Select your favorite </span> <span class='d-block text-center' style="color:black; font-size:20px;">product</span></p> 
            <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Number1.PNG" alt="" 
            style="align-self: center;" width="100" height="100" style="margin-left:500px;">
    
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="semirounded-square-2">
                <div>
                    <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Character_1.png" 
                    alt="" width="250"  style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="row mt-3">
    
        <div class="col-5 border d-flex justify-content-start">
            <p class=" text-right" style="color: #00A0DE; font-size: 50px;">Choose it <span class='d-block' style="color:black; font-size:20px;">Select your favorite </span> <span class='d-block text-center' style="color:black; font-size:20px;">product</span></p> 
            <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Number1.PNG" alt="" 
            style="align-self: center;" width="100" height="100" style="margin-left:500px;">
    
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="semirounded-square-2">
                <div>
                    <img src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Character_1.png" 
                    alt="" width="250"  style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. Code only answers are hard to understand and such hard to reproduce. Without sufficient explaination the everyone will have a hard time to understand what you changed and how your answer would work. Please add a sufficient explaination.